Express.js server .get() not responding on localhost
I'm currently learning web development and working with Express.js and Node.js. The issue I'm encountering is when I try to access http://localhost:3000/ or http://localhost:3001/ (I've also tried changing the port to 3001) in my web browser , nothing happens. I'm not receiving any response from the server and "Test1" is not even printing/outputing/logging on the terminal.
I've set up a simple Express server with the following code:
import express from "express";
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Test1");
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});

I've checked the server console and there are no error messages.
This is what the explorer looks like:
explorer
This is what the terminal shows when I run the command node index.js:
terminal
This is what the package.json file contains:
package.json
I have node version v22.1.0. installed on my wsl/vsCode.
Could someone please help me troubleshoot this issue? I've used similar code before and i could have sworn it worked fine, but now it's not responding and I'm not sure what could be causing the problem. I've spent hours trying to troubleshoot; this a desperate attempt to resolve the issue lol. Would appreciate the help!

The code looks correct, make sure there are not any already running process on specified port.

Hello Ravi. Thank you, this solution worked! I'm facepalming right now because Idk how I overlooked that. I've used two ports (3000 and 3001) to ensure it wasn't a port being used/blocked and the problem still occurred. After reading your comment I've tried a third port, 8080, and that seemed to work. Thanks again!

You are welcome Davie! Glad to help.

My code was similar but I was calling app.use(cors);
app.use(bodyParser.json());  and found that if middleware fails your server will not respond.

This was the fix for me (suggestion by @Ravi Yadav):
What fixed it for me was using a separate port, in my case: 8080. and entered  http://localhost:8080/ instead of http://localhost:3000/ I just played around with different ports to see which ones worked.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Importing Express:
I just started learning Nodejs today, and I noticed that using import express from "express" doesn't work right away. Instead, try this:
const express = require("express");

This is a more common way of importing modules in Node.js, and it should work just fine for you.
Using Nodemon:
To make your life easier during development, there's a tool called nodemon. First, install it globally:
npm install -g nodemon

Then, whenever you want to run your Node.js script, use nodemon instead of node. For example:
nodemon index.js

This will automatically restart your server whenever you make changes to your code, saving you from manually restarting it each time.

Hey. I've just tried that and the problem still persisted. So VsCode gives me an error whenever I try using const express = require("express"); while having type set to module on package.
But i still did what u suggested and removed the type: module from package. I also installed nodemon and ran the 'nodemon index.js' command. It didn't work.

maybe check for the Firewall or Antivirus, they might block your port firewall or antivirus software might block incoming connections on certain ports. Make sure that port 3000 (or 3001) is not blocked by your firewall or antivirus software.
and I remember when I first ran my project it asked me that node would use public network search about this, I am sorry I wasn't of a big help I just started today :(

Your "index.js" and "package.json" files seems correct. However there are few things you should check:

Ensure that the port 3000 is not used by another process. You already tried different port but it's better to run this command: taskkill /PID <PID> /F If the port is being used by another process, you can kill it or change the port you are using. To kill a port, run this command: kill -9 <PID>. Replace  with the process ID from the previous command.

If the port is blocked by the firewall, you cannot use it. Check your firewall settings.

Try clearing your browser cache or testing in an incognito window.

If you're running this on a network (like a workplace or school network), there might be restrictions on accessing certain ports. Try running it on a different network to see if that's the issue. For example, I am usually using the computer at the library in my neighborhood because I don't have a computer. I cannot open public port on the library's computer.

Delete the node_modules/ folder. Then run npm i to reinstall packages.

Use the LTS version of Node.


I hope one of them works for you
